# Dreambooth how to capture images?

Tags: stable-diffusion

I have collected a set of images and separate text files with caption for each image. The text files  have the same name as the image file, but with a different extension (txt). Then I try to train using default instructions for training:

```
export MODEL_NAME="stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-1"
export INSTANCE_DIR="/path/to/images"
export OUTPUT_DIR="/output/path/"

  
accelerate launch train_dreambooth.py \
  --pretrained_model_name_or_path=$MODEL_NAME  \
  --instance_data_dir=$INSTANCE_DIR \
  --output_dir=$OUTPUT_DIR \
  --instance_prompt="a painting by [s]" \
  --resolution=768 \
  --train_batch_size=1 \
  --gradient_accumulation_steps=1 --gradient_checkpointing \
  --use_8bit_adam \
  --enable_xformers_memory_efficient_attention \
  --set_grads_to_none \
  --learning_rate=2e-6 \
  --lr_scheduler="constant" \
  --lr_warmup_steps=0 \
  --max_train_steps=800
```

But sample script considers text files as images and razes error that they are not images

```
  UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 
'/path/to/images/00171-0-20181124_131525.txt'
```

How to caption the images properly?